# Data Designer "Events"

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, data-designer

I am well aware of how attribute groups and populations work in the data designer, however I have never really worked out what the purpose of the events is. I haven't been able to find much in the documentation either.

Does anybody use this functionality or have a use case for why you would need events over just creating a regular attribute group or population?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a small chat about this with a MC Architect and was given an explanation that it's not really used by almost anyone these days since Automation Studio and Journey Builder are now more functional.

On top of that, apparently the Populations and Events will be discontinued in not so distant future.

There is a pretty clear use case [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_events.htm&type=5) in their help portal.
Overall it seems to be creating an audience based on some specific action/trigger points, which you can use in your triggered sends or Journey.